# repositoryPath not respected during nuget package upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with NuGet Package Manager 3.4.3. I have a custom folder for the packages set up. Basically, following entry is added to NuGet.Config in Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

```
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\NugetPackages" />
  </config>
```

My solution builds fine but after I update my package using the "Updates" of the NuGet Package Manager, I see the newer version package ADDED with a RELATIVE path. So, in the csproj file, instead of replacing

```
<Import Project="C:\NugetPackges\xxx.Version1\build\net45\xxx.props" .../>
```

with

```
<Import Project="C:\NugetPackges\xxx.Version2\build\net45\xxx.props" .../>
```

It ADDED an additional entry with RELATIVE path

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\..\NugetPackges\xxx.Version2\build\net45\xxx.props" .../>
```

Why isn't the absolute path respected during upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Nuget Package Manager always adds a reference to the Nuget package, as a relative path of the Repository folder(specified in Nuget.config) from the .csProj file of the project it is referenced in. So while upgrading the project from one version to another it will look for the relative path of the repository folder and add a reference as a relative path.